# How can I use jQuery to simultaneously toggle classes & toggle content?

Tags: jquery, class, replace, toggle

I have a span in a header which toggles a list's visibility. Initially I had one empty & un-classed span, with jQuery toggling the span's class, and generated content in css changing its content (a symbol). However, since IE7 fails at generated content, I had to rebuild the thing using two classed & content-populated spans - not horrible, but if I can somehow combine a .toggleClass & .replaceWith, that would be cool because it would enable me to simplify the markup - a single, empty, un-classed span. The problems I encountered was not toggling the class on the subsequent click but rather reverting the content.

The current working version:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#semantic-id h3').click(function() {
            $(this).parent('div').find('ul').slideToggle(333);
            $(this).find('span').toggle();
            return false;
        });

        $('#semantic-id h3 a').click(function() {
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="semantic-id">
    <h3>
        <span class="open-it">[ + ]</span>
        <span class="close-it">[ - ]</span>
        A List of Things
        <a href="#" title="Add Another One">Add Another One</a>
    </h3>
    <ul> ... </ul>
</div><!--  END div id="semantic-id"    -->
```

... and what I'd prefer is that the markup is:

```
<div id="semantic-id">
    <h3>
        <span>&nbsp;</span> A List of Things
        <a href="#" title="Add Another One">Add Another One</a>
    </h3>
    <ul> ... </ul>
</div><!--  END div id="semantic-id"    -->
```

I've tried various combinations of toggleClass, replaceWIth methods, but I was unable to revert to original state on the 2nd click, i.e., close the box, revert the class *and* the content of the div.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please revisit your previous questions and either mark the appropriate answer as accepted, or post the answer you chose and close it.

Comment: thx Brad. I've closed a couple; one of the others I'll have to dig up my solution and post it, and the other issue has no complete answer, I'll have to revisit that when time allows ... do those unclosed issues prevent anyone from responding to this one? cheers,svs

Comment: This answer helped me with a similar situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198138/jquery-toggle-with-toggleclass/5198156#5198156